# How to copy directories with spaces in the name

Tags: directory, spaces, robocopy

I am trying to use robocopy but am unable to make it work because of spaces in the directory names.
I am trying to copy 3 directories: My Documents, My Music and My Pictures to 'C:\test-backup' but want the end result to be
'C:\test-backup\My Documents'
'C:\test-backup\My Music'
'C:\test-backup\My Pictures'

My command does not work:
`robocopy C:\Users\Angie C:\test-backup "My Documents" /B /E /R:0 /CREATE /NP /TEE /XJ /LOG+:"CompleteBackupLog.txt"`

No matter what I do, it’s just not happening. Anybody have any suggestions or tricks?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What's with separating `My Documents` from `C:\test-backup`? And why the quotes only around `My Documents`?

I'm assuming it's a typo, try using `robocopy C:\Users\Angie "C:\test-backup\My Documents" /B /E /R:0 /CREATE /NP /TEE /XJ /LOG+:"CompleteBackupLog.txt"`

**[Edit:]** Since the syntax the documentation specifies (`robocopy <Source> <Destination> [<File>[ ...]]`) says *File*, it might not work with *Folders*.

You'll have to use`robocopy "C:\Users\Angie\My Documents" "C:\test-backup\My Documents" /B /E /R:0 /CREATE /NP /TEE /XJ /LOG+:"CompleteBackupLog.txt"`

Comment: According to [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx) the syntax is 'robocopy <Source> <Destination> [<File>[ ...]] [<Options>]' so in my case, I want to copy the My Documents folder. If I use the code you're showing me, will it not copy **everything** in 'C:\Users\Angie' to 'C:\test-backup\My Documents' instead of just My Documents?

Comment: YatharthROCK: Yes, I think your edit is what I will have to do. Sorry about the confusion, I had hoped that I could list the three folder names in the command rather than write three separate commands... But that is OK, as long as it works :o) Thank you.

Comment: @Angie Did you know  have _no_ idea what Robocopy is or what it's about? I only skimmed this stuff from the docs. And the link too, you provided me. Sometimes you're very close to an answer, you just need to search a bit more *:)*

Answer (score 130):

After some trial and error and observing the results (in other words, I hacked it), I got it to work.

Quotes ARE required to use a path name with spaces.  The trick is there MUST be a space after the path names before the closing quote...like this...

```
robocopy "C:\Source Path " "C:\Destination Path " /option1 /option2...
```

This almost seems like a bug and certainly not very intuitive.

Todd K.

Comment: Todd,   thanks for that. For clarity: `"C:\source path\ "` (there's a space BEFORE the closing quote

Comment: Wow, what an extremely unintuitive requirement! Thanks Todd!

Comment: I see in another answer the cause -- the last backslash is treated as an escape character, so I'm not sure if your example applies to this "space after closing quote" requirement? In any event, thanks for the heads up on this peculiarity (I am not OP, just passer-by). Definitely still seems like a bug more than anything, else Robocopy is really dumb. After all, it isn't confused by the first 'escaped' quote.

Comment: Not likely a bug, but definitely a bug, undocumented as well! For whom it might concern "mir option" call in java: "ROBOCOPY " + "\"" + srcpath.replace("/", "\\")  + " \"" +  " \""+ targetpath.replace("/", "\\") + " \"" + " /MIR"

Comment: Thanks very much.  It seems like a robocopy parsing design flaw or long standing bug.

Comment: just a note that these problems are caused by the CMD shell parser, not robocopy. they'll never fix them, I think we are meant to move onto PowerShell

Comment: @BenMcIntyre The problem persists in PowerShell. You either have to to add a space after the last back slash or omit the last back slash at all.

Comment: just a note that these problems are caused by the Powershell shell parser, not robocopy. they'll never fix them, I think we are meant to move onto Unix (MINGW!)

Answer (score 45):

There's no need to add space before closing quote if path doesn't contain trailing backslash, so following command should work:

```
robocopy "C:\Source Path" "C:\Destination Path" /option1 /option2...
```

But, following will not work:

```
robocopy "C:\Source Path\" "C:\Destination Path\" /option1 /option2...
```

This is due to the escaping issue that is described [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html):

> The \ escape can cause problems with quoted directory paths that
>   contain a trailing backslash because the closing quote " at the end of
>   the line will be escaped \".

Comment: Thank you for the contextual details behind this behavior. Now it makes some sense, as unintuitive as it may remain. Certainly they could/should have done better than this, programmatically. It's pretty easy to assume what the intent is in most all these cases.  After all, it isn't confused by the first 'escaped' quote.

Comment: This saved me quite a bit of command line grief. thank you for sharing!

Comment: Very good explanation. In comparison to toddk63's answer, this really explains why two possibilities are working. People who like the trailing backslash to clarify that this is a folder need an additional space since robocopy picks it up as escape character before the double quotes. If the trailing backslash is omitted, he space is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 8):

There is a bug in robocopy in interpreting the source name. If you include a back slash at the end of the path to describe a folder it keeps including the string for the source into the rest of the line. ie

robocopy "C:\back up\" %destination% /e Nothing here will go to the destination string

robocopy "C:\back up" %destination% /e  but this works

I may be wrong but I think both should work!

Answer (score 2):

```
robocopy "C:\Users\Angie\My Documents" "C:\test-backup\My Documents" /B /E /R:0 /CREATE /NP /TEE /XJ /LOG+:"CompleteBackupLog.txt"
robocopy "C:\Users\Angie\My Music" "C:\test-backup\My Music" /B /E /R:0 /CREATE /NP /TEE /XJ /LOG+:"CompleteBackupLog.txt"
robocopy "C:\Users\Angie\My Pictures" "C:\test-backup\My Pictures" /B /E /R:0 /CREATE /NP /TEE /XJ /LOG+:"CompleteBackupLog.txt"
```

Comment: Will that not copy **everything** in 'C:\Users\Angie' and place it in 'C:\test-backup\My Documents'? I only want to copy the three folders mentioned above and thought I could list them in the command.  'robocopy <Source> <Destination> [<File>[ ...]] [<Options>]'

Answer (score 1):

When you specify the last Directory on the path remove the last .

for example  "\server\directory with space\directory with space".

that should do it.

Answer (score -3):

You should write brackets only before path: `"c:\program files\`

Answer (score -4):

If this folder is the first in the command then it won't work with a space in the folder name, so replace the space in the folder name with an underscore.

Comment: is not a direct answer, but still is a suggestion that could solve the  problem

Comment: Is `Rename 'My Documents' to 'My_Documents'` *really* an a useful suggestion though? What about `Program Files`?

Comment: This is a work around, not an answer. Consider showing examples of how to fix the problem.